# How to get most repeated object property value using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am new to lodash and was wondering how I could use it to get the most repeated property value in an object array. Like say I have an array such as

```
var arr1 = [{points: 50, player: LeBron James},{points: 32, player: Kevin Durant},{points: 62, player: LeBron James},{points: 90, player: LeBron James}]
```

In the player property in arr1, "LeBron James" is the most repeated. How would I get this using lodash? Thanks again.

Comment: Please post the code which you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `_.uniqBy()` It creates duplicate-free version of an array.

```js
var objects = [{points: 50, player: 'LeBron James'},{points: 32, player: 'Kevin Durant'},{points: 62, player: 'LeBron James'},{points: 90, player: 'LeBron James'}];

var result = _.head(_(objects)
  .countBy('player')
  .entries()
  .maxBy(_.last));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it only returns the array without duplicates - Is there anyway to identify that "LeBron James" is the most repeated player in the object array using lodash?

Comment: Run the code snippet. It show the result that you asked.